# Notation in linear algebra vector space question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

What does the bar over alpha and beta mean here(see image attached). 
The question was :
 If V = set of all vectors and F is a field of real no’s then prove V is a vector space.[image]

Comment: your question is about the bar notation, right?

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw Yes

Comment: Huh - not sure why my answer is downvoted then. Let me know if you want any clarification!

Comment: Compare to other notation like $\vec{\alpha}$.  It is merely a stylistic choice to make visually distinct from $\alpha$ with no mathematical significance, similar to how we might vary the font or vary the capitalization.

Comment: Great suggestion- updated!

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax - here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bar notation is being used to distinguish between vectors and scalars. That is, $\bar{\alpha} \in V$ is a vector while $a \in F$ is a scalar.

There are other notations one could use to distinguish vectors from scalars. For example, vectors could be written in bold like $\boldsymbol{\alpha} \in V$ or with little arrows on top of them like $\vec{\alpha} \in V$. You could also choose to not differentiate vectors in this way and hope that is is clear from context.

Either way, this is all mainly a stylistic choice.